# Angular - Apply class to component root element not selector

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a card component in my app.  Based off what type of card it is there is a different style that needs to be applied to the root element of the template.  When I do this:

```
<card class="card-type-class"></card>
```

My html ends up looking like this:

```
<card class="card-type-class">
    <div class="other-constant-classes">
        content of my card
    </div>
</card>
```

Instead of like this:

```
<card>
    <div class="other-constant-classes card-type-class">
        content of my card
    </div>
</card>
```

Is there anyway to apply classes from the selector to the root element of the component template?

***Sorry if this has been asked, I had a hard time figuring out how to search for that question...

Comment: would an attribute based selector work ? `selector: '[tn-labelfor]',` usage `<label tn-labelfor ` change stuff `this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement,'class','my class');`

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always pass in the class as a string:

```
<card [myClass]="'card-type-class'"></card>
```

Then in the lower component:

```
@Input() myClass: string;
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="other-constant-classes {{myClass}}">
    content of my card
</div>
```